# SwiftUI to UIkit backBarButtonItem empty title creates a space

Tags: swiftui, uikit

In my Storyboard app I'm now starting to include SwiftUI views. I'm navigating from a SwiftUI view to an old UIkit VC and would like to ensure my navigation bar is the same as all other screen which, in this case, is a custom title and back button with the back arrow only, no text.

My storyboard VC viewDidLoad looks like this coming from a SwiftUI view:

```
 override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        DispatchQueue.main.async { [self] in
            
            self.navigationController?.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "", style: .plain, target: nil, action: nil)
            
            let label1 = UILabel()
            label1.text = "Manage Your Account"
            label1.font = UIFont(name: "Raleway-Bold", size: 16)
            label1.textColor = .white
            label1.sizeToFit()
            
            self.navigationController?.navigationBar.topItem?.titleView = label1
            
            self.navigationController?.navigationBar.topItem?.rightBarButtonItems?.append(UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .add, target: self, action: #selector(self.addAccountBtn(_:))))

        }
        
        //Required for table view
        userAcctTableView.dataSource = self
        userAcctTableView.delegate = self
        
    }
```

My issue is the space created where the Back is suppose to be (yellow bloc) and because of this it pushes my title off centre (purple).

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This was simply fixed by changing the order of the code lines:

```
let label1 = UILabel()
            label1.text = "Manage Your Account"
            label1.font = UIFont(name: "Raleway-Bold", size: 16)
            label1.textColor = .white
            label1.sizeToFit()
            
            self.navigationController?.navigationBar.topItem?.titleView = label1
            self.navigationController?.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "", style: .plain, target: nil, action: nil)
            self.navigationController?.navigationBar.topItem?.rightBarButtonItems?.append(UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .add, target: self, action: #selector(self.addAccountBtn(_:))))
```